# Three boolean values saved in one tinyint

Tags: type-conversion

probably a simple question but I seem to be suffering from  programmer's block. :)

I have three boolean values: A, B, and C. I would like to save the state combination as an unsigned tinyint (max 255) into a database and be able to derive the states from the saved integer. 
Even though there are only a limited number of combinations, I would like to avoid hard-coding each state combination to a specific value (something like if A=true and B=true has the value 1).

I tried to assign values to the variables so (A=1, B=2, C=3) and then adding, but I can't differentiate between A and B being true from i.e. only C being true.

I am stumped but pretty sure that it is possible.
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you want a bitfield. Look into coding them as powers of two.

Comment: Joe, why not post this as an answer?

Comment: Good point. I suppose I just wanted to give a quick pointer rather than give a full answer. Often giving answers requires giving full code samples when a 'look in this direction' will do. Then you get downvoted...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Binary maths  I think. Choose a location that's a power of 2 (1, 2, 4, 8 etch) then you can use the 'bitwise and' operator & to determine the value.
Say A = 1, B = 2 , C= 4

00000111 => A B and C => 7

00000101 => A and C   => 5

00000100 =>  C => 4

then to determine them :

```
if( val  & 4 ) // same as if (C)
if( val  & 2 ) // same as if (B)
if( val  & 1 ) // same as if (A)

if((val  & 4) && (val & 2)  ) // same as if (C and B)
```

No need for a state table.

Edit: to reflect comment
If the tinyint has a maximum value of 255 => you have 8 bits to play with and can store 8 boolean values in there

Comment: So it's possible to save how many boolean values in an 8-bit tinyint? As many as there are BITS in it: eight. One bit = one value of 1 or 0 which is exactly what is needed for a boolean. (Just thought it would be nice to explain for those who haven't studied this.)

Answer (score 1):

binary math as others have said

encoding:

```
myTinyInt = A*1 + B*2 + C*4 (assuming you convert A,B,C to 0 or 1 beforehand)
```

decoding

```
bool A = myTinyInt & 1 != 0 (& is the bitwise and operator in many languages)
bool B = myTinyInt & 2 != 0
bool C = myTinyInt & 4 != 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll add that you should find a way to **not use magic numbers**.  You can build masks into constants using the [Left Logical/Bit Shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift) with a constant bit position that is the position of the flag of interest in the bit field.  (Wow... that makes almost no sense.)  An example in C++ would be:

```
enum Flags {
    kBitMask_A = (1 << 0),
    kBitMask_B = (1 << 1),
    kBitMask_C = (1 << 2),
};

uint8_t byte = 0;        //          byte = 0b00000000
byte |= kBitMask_A;      // Set A,   byte = 0b00000001
byte |= kBitMask_C;      // Set C,   byte = 0b00000101
if (byte & kBitMask_A) { // Test A,  (0b00000101 & 0b00000001) = T
    byte &= ~kBitMask_A; // Clear A, byte = 0b00000100
}
```

In any case, I would recommend looking for [Bitset support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitset#Language_support) in your favorite programming language.  Many languages will abstract the logical operations away behind normal arithmetic or "test/set" operations.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use binary...

A = 1,
B = 2,
C = 4,
D = 8,
E = 16,
F = 32, 
G = 64,
H = 128

This means A + B = 3 but C = 4. You'll never have two conflicting values. I've listed the maximum you can have for a single byte, 8 values or (bits).